# How to assign dynamically fetched variable to HREF, Jquery, laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new to development, apologies if question is basic

I am trying to add href page to the btn, but when the blade template parses url it's formatted and return error.

```
 $('#municipal_option').on('change',function(e){
        // console.log(e);  
        var municipal_id = e.target.value; 
        var BASEURL = "{!! url('admin/bank/') !!}";
        console.log(municipal_id);
        $.get( BASEURL + '/bankview?municipal_id=' + municipal_id, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $("#bank_list tr").remove();
            $.each(data,function(index, bankObj){
                $('#bank_list').append('<tr class=""><td> ' + bankObj.bank_name + '</td> <td> ' + bankObj.bank_ac_no + ' </td>  <td> '+ bankObj.bank_ifsc_code +' </td> <td> <button class="btn btn-primary"> **<a href="{!! asset('bank/{{$bank->id}}/edit')!!}"> Edit </a>**  </td> <td> </td>    </tr>');


             });
});
});
```

The route:

```
| GET|HEAD  | bank/{bank}/edit   | bank.edit   | App\Http\Controllers\bankController@edit
```

How to point to the above route.

The url that's generated, 
http://localhost/public/bank/%3C?php%20echo%20e($bank-%3Eid);%20?%3E/edit

Adding to the above question, 
Instead of looping the result(table) in the code, can I use it independently in the blade template with hep of @foreach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was trying to print an action route from a Javascript code, it was trying to print the php echo code directly, hence it yielded no result for the function.

```
<a href="/your_route/' + bankObj.id + '">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Javascript to replace the custom js value into the route

```
var url = "{{ route('bank.edit', ':municipal_id') }}";

url = url.replace(":municipal_id", municipal_id);
```

so...

```
 $('#municipal_option').on('change',function(e){
            // console.log(e);  
            var municipal_id = e.target.value; 
            var BASEURL = "{{ route('bank.edit', ':municipal_id') }}";
            BASEURL.replace(':municipal_id', municipal_id);
            console.log(municipal_id);
            $.get( BASEURL , function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $("#bank_list tr").remove();
                $.each(data,function(index, bankObj){
                    $('#bank_list').append('<tr class=""><td> ' + bankObj.bank_name + '</td> <td> ' + bankObj.bank_ac_no + ' </td>  <td> '+ bankObj.bank_ifsc_code +' </td> <td> <button class="btn btn-primary"> **<a href="{!! asset('bank/{{$bank->id}}/edit')!!}"> Edit </a>**  </td> <td> </td>    </tr>');


                });
            });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for looking to this. But this will break the first part where I get data from the  path admin/bank. 


I am looking to add edit button and link it to the edit page where it can be accessed based on the id. 

Sorry to say that the above code dont work for me

Comment: I am new to developing, just incase if am pointing it wrong, please correct me

Comment: If you want to make a button to go to a edit page, just do

`<button onclick="location.href='{{route("bank,edit", $id)}}'"></button>`

If you generate the buttons via javascript, replace $id with the javascript value

Comment: Thanks @Juan, actually I replaced the href to <a href="bank/'+ bankObj.id +'/edit">'